# using .9.png tool to make gradual png

Tags: android, nine-patch

I know how to use the .9.png tool to make a common .9.png, but I want to use the tool to make a gradual png.

First I make a gradual PNG using Photoshop, then I put the the .9.png into the .9 tool.  The gradual PNG is changed, sometimes the change is very big, so the .9.png gradual PNG doesn't look good.

So my question is if there is some skill or trick to make a good .9.png with a gradual effect.  I do not want to use common gradual PNG because it occupies too much space, and the built-in system .9.png doesn't look good either.  Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer for your question but you may find it useful. try using gradient color instead:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html

[Android: Using linear gradient as background looks banded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928101/android-using-linear-gradient-as-background-looks-banded)

[Android LinearLayout Gradient Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976805/android-linearlayout-gradient-background)

**EDIT:** also consider using tiles as described in [How to make android app's background image repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706913/how-to-make-android-apps-background-image-repeat) and in [How to make android app's background image repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706913/how-to-make-android-apps-background-image-repeat)

Comment: thanks,i know how to use gradient color instead,but i am know using which colors can make a good effect,if there is  some tool that can view the color change,then i can put the color to the xml

Answer (score 1):

Here are links for the tutorial abouth draw9patch
you can refer it,I have just googled and found this useful links

http://android10.org/index.php/articlesother/279-draw-9-patch-tutorial

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfrXE2R2nqM

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzdZ_9smcGc

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

My Designer Adviced me once:"While making 9 patch,main thing is to selct pixels from the Left and Top side".

Comment: thanks i have look http://android10.org/index.php/articlesother/279-draw-9-patch-tutorial,my problem is that when i frist using a gradual png then put it to the tool,the gradual .9.png  looks  changed,the link not give some good practice,only give how to using the tool to make a .9.png

Comment: yeh sure can you post your image that you want to make in .9.png in post