# How to programmatically show/hide only the background/image of an ImageView in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, alpha, android-background

I have an `ImageView`, and its alpha is set to 0 in the XML. The XML looks like this:

```xml
<LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="<height>"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/<id>"
                android:layout_width="<width>"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:alpha="0"
                android:background="#ff00ff"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/<drawable>" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/<id>"
                android:layout_width="<width>"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:alpha="0"
                android:background="#0000ff"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/<drawable>" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried searching how to do this, but most questions are about how to hide the background or the entire `ImageView`, and not just the background. Also, the `alpha` has to be set to `"0"`. Is there any way to hide only the image so that only the `background` (solid color) is visible? Only the `background` colors of both `ImageView`s have to be displayed, so the container (`LinearLayout`)'s `background` cannot be used to do this for both (the background colors are different).

Changing the image's source to an image which is a solid color, the same as the background color, would work, but I need to change this color programmatically, so it might be inefficient. I've also tried different combinations of `ImageView.`- `setAlpha(float)`, `setImageAlpha(int)`, `setImageResource(int)` (to `0`) and `setImageDrawable(Drawable)` (to show the image again, with the background [color]), but they produce weird results. Using `setImageResource(0)` (with alpha `1f`) hides the image, showing only the solid background, but I'm not able to display the image again. Is there any easy method I'm unaware of?

I need to do this programmatically, so methods like in [Java android Linearlayout set two colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154644/java-android-linearlayout-set-two-colors) wouldn't work. What is the best way to do this programmatically?

Comment: Can't you use 2 ImageViews one over the other. One with solid background color which can change dynamically at run time and the other ImageView with a drawable that you can set the visibility to visible/non-visible?

Comment: @Lakshmi, yes, even I thought of that, and I guess that would work (I guess I'd have to change that Z-index attribute to hide the `ImageView`s below each other). But I doubt if having 2 `ImageView`s for every 1 would be efficient, as the XML has many like these two. I mean, there must be some way to change the same `ImageView`'s properties to show/hide *only* the background or the image, no? I thought you could change some XML attributes, etc., to create some kind of XML style/class which I can use instead of the `ImageView`; or some Java code to manipulate the same view.

Comment: Explore LayerDrawable class.
It says it can be defined in an XML file with the <layer-list> element. Each Drawable in the layer is defined in a nested <item>. 
I think you can define different layers and that is the solution to your problem.
Check this link for more information.
https://medium.com/@akashjha/multiimageview-with-layerlist-ebb16a0850af

Comment: @Lakshmi, thanks for the information; I'll try it. But again, I'm not sure if adding another element is needed or efficient. The code in the website you linked looks simple and easy to implement, but again, it's *not the same View*.

Comment: Can't you use **imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);** and      **imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_drawable);**

Comment: don't search for show/hide the imageView background but search for image placeholders you can easily achieve this using somethings like Picasso or glide.
or you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192545/how-to-put-new-placeholder-resources-into-android-studio-project-toolssample

Comment: @NiranjPatel, no, they produce weird results.

Comment: @PouyaDanesh, but additional dependencies are needed, and they seem like heavy libraries and so not efficient, either.

Comment: don't use them just search for image placeholders and you'll find your answer

Comment: @PouyaDanesh, but it still seems like it's not efficient and isn't suitable for my use case. The results I get are about the libraries and placeholder widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not directly possible to work it as expected with two views, and as you said, you have multiple views like that & that's why it's not memory efficient.

But We can achieve that functionality using **`CustomView`** designed according to our needs.

**If you know a little bit of `drawing on the canvas` and how it works, then it'll be easier.**

Here, I made the custom view to achieve exactly what you want.

```
public class ImageAlphaBGView extends View {
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    Paint mPaint;
    Paint mPaintBG;
    Rect bgRect;

    private int mWidth;
    private int mHeight;
    float centreX;
    float centreY;

    public ImageAlphaBGView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ImageAlphaBGView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ImageAlphaBGView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public ImageAlphaBGView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        mPaintBG = new Paint();
        mPaintBG.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        mPaintBG.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaintBG.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
        try {
            centreX = (mWidth - bitmap.getWidth()) / 2;
            centreY = (mHeight - bitmap.getHeight()) / 2;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setBGColor(int color) {
        mPaintBG.setColor(color);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setImageAlpha(@IntRange(from = 0, to = 255) int alpha) {
        mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setBGAlpha(@IntRange(from = 0, to = 255) int alpha) {
        mPaintBG.setAlpha(alpha);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRect(bgRect, mPaintBG);
        if (bitmap != null)
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, centreX, centreY, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mWidth = w;
        mHeight = h;

        bgRect = new Rect(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Simply put this view in your xml & then you can programmatically pass a bitmap and alpha of the background.

It supports setting up **image alpha, background alpha seperately** as well as background color.

**Here is what you need to do :**

**In the xml,**

```
<com.demo.example.views.ImageAlphaBGView
            android:id="@+id/alphaView"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"/>
```

**In the activity or fragment,**

```
ImageAlphaBGView imageView = findViewById(R.id.alphaView)
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
imageView.setBGColor(Color.RED)
imageView.setImageAlpha(255)
```

**And you've got it. :)**

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/custom-views/custom-drawing

Answer (score 2):

Imageview can show a bitmap as you know. You can set the bitmap by deleting the background of the relevant bitmap.

Main Object

```
object BackgroundRemover {

    private val segment: Segmenter
    private var buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(0)
    private var width = 0
    private var height = 0


    init {
        val segmentOptions = SelfieSegmenterOptions.Builder()
            .setDetectorMode(SelfieSegmenterOptions.SINGLE_IMAGE_MODE)
            .build()
        segment = Segmentation.getClient(segmentOptions)
    }


    /**
     * Process the image to get buffer and image height and width
     * @param bitmap Bitmap which you want to remove background.
     * @param trimEmptyPart After removing the background if its true it will remove the empty part of bitmap. by default its false.
     * @param listener listener for success and failure callback.
     **/
    fun bitmapForProcessing(
        bitmap: Bitmap,
        trimEmptyPart: Boolean? = false,
        listener: OnBackgroundChangeListener
    ) {
        //Generate a copy of bitmap just in case the if the bitmap is immutable.
        val copyBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
        val input = InputImage.fromBitmap(copyBitmap, 0)
        segment.process(input)
            .addOnSuccessListener { segmentationMask ->
                buffer = segmentationMask.buffer
                width = segmentationMask.width
                height = segmentationMask.height

                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    val time = measureTimeMillis {
                        val resultBitmap = if (trimEmptyPart == true) {
                            val bgRemovedBitmap = removeBackgroundFromImage(copyBitmap)
                            trim(bgRemovedBitmap)
                        } else {
                            removeBackgroundFromImage(copyBitmap)
                        }
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            listener.onSuccess(resultBitmap)
                        }
                    }
                    Log.e("TAG", "bitmapForProcessingTime: $time")
                }

            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                println("Image processing failed: $e")
                listener.onFailed(e)

            }
    }


    /**
     * Change the background pixels color to transparent.
     * */
    private suspend fun removeBackgroundFromImage(
        image: Bitmap
    ): Bitmap {
        val bitmap = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
            for (y in 0 until height) {
                for (x in 0 until width) {
                    val bgConfidence = ((1.0 - buffer.float) * 255).toInt()
                    if (bgConfidence >= 100) {
                        image.setHasAlpha(true)
                        image.setPixel(x, y, 0)
                    }
                }
            }
            buffer.rewind()
            return@async image
        }
        return bitmap.await()
    }


    /**
     * trim the empty part of a bitmap.
     **/
    private suspend fun trim(
        bitmap: Bitmap
    ): Bitmap {
        val result = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).async {
            var firstX = 0
            var firstY = 0
            var lastX = bitmap.width
            var lastY = bitmap.height
            val pixels = IntArray(bitmap.width * bitmap.height)
            bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, bitmap.width, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height)
            loop@ for (x in 0 until bitmap.width) {
                for (y in 0 until bitmap.height) {
                    if (pixels[x + y * bitmap.width] != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                        firstX = x
                        break@loop
                    }
                }
            }
            loop@ for (y in 0 until bitmap.height) {
                for (x in firstX until bitmap.width) {
                    if (pixels[x + y * bitmap.width] != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                        firstY = y
                        break@loop
                    }
                }
            }
            loop@ for (x in bitmap.width - 1 downTo firstX) {
                for (y in bitmap.height - 1 downTo firstY) {
                    if (pixels[x + y * bitmap.width] != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                        lastX = x
                        break@loop
                    }
                }
            }
            loop@ for (y in bitmap.height - 1 downTo firstY) {
                for (x in bitmap.width - 1 downTo firstX) {
                    if (pixels[x + y * bitmap.width] != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                        lastY = y
                        break@loop
                    }
                }
            }
            return@async Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, firstX, firstY, lastX - firstX, lastY - firstY)
        }
        return result.await()
    }

}
```

Listener

```
interface OnBackgroundChangeListener {

    fun onSuccess(bitmap: Bitmap)

    fun onFailed(exception: Exception)

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm using Java (I tried converting this to Java, but it showed some error, probably because I've not installed the dependencies). I forgot about Bitmaps, but I don't think using Google's ML Kit, etc., is needed or would be efficient, as I have to do this many times, at runtime. Wait- did you misread it as 'to *remove* the background from the image' by chance? Sorry, but I'm trying to *hide* the solid `background` color from the *`ImageView`* (the Android widget, not the image that is displayed in the `ImageView`).