# How to create gradient Background splash screen in react native application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to create gradient Background splash screen in my react native application but I'm unable to find sources for it, can anyone pls help me out of it

Comment: You can use react-native-splash-screen from npm and prepare splashcreen using xml like in the readme

Comment: i been gone through it but there is no gradient option in it

Comment: There is. But instead of writing code like for React Native, you have to look for the solution like for android/ios application. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976805/android-linearlayout-gradient-background

Comment: And another option, if you want to write this splash screen in RN. You can use the above plugin to disable the default splash screen and use the first screen of your RN application. With a simple timeout you can set a time to move to the next view. For gradients in react native you can use "react-native-linear-gradient" from npm. I have been using this component some time ago for button background in my application.

Comment: @WonkyWan, can you tell us how to disable the default splash screen in react-native-splash-screen?